# How to get data from python

Tags: python, string

```
data = obj.generateSession("P78013","Ujhdy@2")
print(data)
```

The result printed in the following format

> {'status': True, 'message': 'SUCCESS', 'errorcode': '', 'data':
> {'clientcode': 'K98913', 'name': 'HPP', 'email': '',
> 'mobileno': '', 'exchanges': ['bse_cm', 'cde_fo', 'mcx_fo', 'ncx_fo',
> 'nse_cm', 'nse_fo'], 'products': ['CNC', 'NRML', 'MARGIN', 'MIS',
> 'BO', 'CO'], 'lastlogintime': '', 'broker': '', 'jwtToken': 'Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Iko4ODkxMyIsInJvbGVzIjowLCJ1c2VydHlwZSI6IlVTRVIiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTU3NTAxNDksImV4cCI6MTc0MjE1MDE0OX0.P1Ne0T0lTgScZJ1udMYRaJ32WeNDB-bZIwMg4uSAGC4RDFnYRsdvXGRyIEx7KS1LpQ6ndRIt7UjoyIewCs7HLA',
> 'refreshToken':
> 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IlJFRlJFU0gtVE9LRU4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTU3NTAxNDl9.9DM1ggWfaervPe3qCpoDywfdb8kJ6okQrqZeR_mjsbGliqM7w0DdRyxTHyB7m-742Sfj9tVsZ4qQrOK0RQ9TmQ'}}

i am trying to filter out the 'jwtToken' value in the string format like below

jwtToken='Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI.....'

Comment: And what have you tried?  This is one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to extract it

```
re.findall("(jwtToken).?:(.*)\'\,",s)[0]
```

```
('jwtToken',
 " 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Iko4ODkxMyIsInJvbGVzIjowLCJ1c2VydHlwZSI6IlVTRVIiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTU3NTAxNDksImV4cCI6MTc0MjE1MDE0OX0.P1Ne0T0lTgScZJ1udMYRaJ32WeNDB-bZIwMg4uSAGC4RDFnYRsdvXGRyIEx7KS1LpQ6ndRIt7UjoyIewCs7HLA")
```

Answer (score 0):

jwt tokens are just base64encoded json

```
import base64
token="Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Iko4ODkxMyIsInJvbGVzIjowLCJ1c2VydHlwZSI6IlVTRVIiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTU3NTAxNDksImV4cCI6MTc0MjE1MDE0OX0.P1Ne0T0lTgScZJ1udMYRaJ32WeNDB-bZIwMg4uSAGC4RDFnYRsdvXGRyIEx7KS1LpQ6ndRIt7UjoyIewCs7HLA".split(" ")[1]
b64tok = token.split(".",1)[1]
print(base64.b64decode(b64tok))
```